# Semantic distance between two words

Tags: semantics, semantic-markup, wordnet, semantic-analysis

I would like to get a value which identifies the symantec distance between the words.

I know that from wordnet I can get a set of words which are hyponyms, synonyms.... to a particular word.

BUT is there a way to give two words as an input and get a value representing the distance between the two words from wordnet rather than the actual word?

Answer (score 0):

you can get semantic similarity between two words, and you can use that as a distance measure. More the similarity lesser the distance or somehting.